# Searching for newest email with a certain subject

Tags: vba, outlook

I have the below code which works.

I now need to find the newest email with that subject line and open it.

Once the email is opened, I'd like to save the attachment to my desktop and close out of the opened email.

```
 Sub SearchOL()

 Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
 Dim olNs As NameSpace
 Dim Fldr As MAPIFolder
 Dim olMail As Variant
 Dim i As Integer

 Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
 Set olNs = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
 Set Fldr = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
 i = 1
 For Each olMail In Fldr.Items
     If InStr(olMail.Subject, "DNP Warn and Pend Event") <> 0 Then
     olMail.Display
     i = i + 1
     End If
 Next olMail
 End Sub
```

Comment: Anything you have tried?

Comment: If this is VBA in Outlook, you don't need `olApp` at all. Replace it with `Application`. Why display it when you can make another loop to auto save any attachments within the mail item. Please note items in Inbox may not be mail item.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest starting from the [Getting Started with VBA in Outlook 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814736%28v=office.14%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) article in MSDN.

Use the [Find](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff869662.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)/[FindNext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff862482.aspx) or [Restrict](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff869597.aspx) methods of the Items class to find the emails with a particular subject line instead of iterating through each email and checking the subject line.

```
Sub DemoFindNext() 
 Dim myNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace 
 Dim tdystart As Date 
 Dim tdyend As Date 
 Dim myAppointments As Outlook.Items 
 Dim currentAppointment As Outlook.AppointmentItem 

 Set myNameSpace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI") 
 tdystart = VBA.Format(Now, "Short Date") 
 tdyend = VBA.Format(Now + 1, "Short Date") 
 Set myAppointments = myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar).Items 
 Set currentAppointment = myAppointments.Find("[Start] >= """ & tdystart & """ and [Start] <= """ & tdyend & """") 
 While TypeName(currentAppointment) <> "Nothing" 
  MsgBox currentAppointment.Subject 
  Set currentAppointment = myAppointments.FindNext 
 Wend 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through the emails that have the desired subject
Initialize BestRcdDate = 1900-01-01
For each email with the desired subject:
If Rec'd date of Email > BestRcdDate
Then BestRcdDate = rec'd date of email
And save email as DesiedEmail

Comment: Answers are always welcome, no need to justify another one after some time. You may however want to apply [answer], review for typos and apply some formatting based on https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help